# Link to image in separate folder

Tags: html, css

I am hoping this is a simple question.

I have a homepage where i have an image of the facebook icon.
I want that icon to link to another page called facebook.html.
this works by saying

```
 <a href = "clue_links/facebook.html"><img id = "facebook_icon" src =
 "facebook_icon.png" height = "40" width = "40"></a>
```

On the facebook.html page, I am trying to set the background saying:

```
<style>
   background-image: url("clue_images/facebook.jpg");
</style>
```

The html pages are in the clue_links folder and the bg images are in the clue_images folder. Does anyone know why this won't work?

Thanks

Comment: For the bg image you should use url("../clue_images/facebook.jpg"); You need to go up one level first to be able to find the clue_images folder

Comment: @Gerard tried it this way and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: url("../clue_images/facebook.jpg");
```

Comment: tried this way and it wont load. it will only load when i give the full URL file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/project/project/clue_images/facebook.jpg

Comment: realised I had a typo when changing it. This works now thank you

Answer (score 0):

your path for the background image is incorrect on the style. try this

```
background: url("../clue_images/facebook.jpg");
```